# Fortune Favors the Bold

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, poetry

I have seen quite a few translations such as,

> *Audentes Fortuna Juvas*
>   *Audentis Fortuna Iuvat*
>   *Audecis Fortuna Juvat*

But, what is the correct translation? I am looking for the one which matches Virgil's Aeneid the best.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking to quote the Aeneid, here's the relevant section, from X.279-84.

> *quod votis optastis adest, perfringere dextra.
>
>   in manibus Mars ipse viris. nunc coniugis esto
>
>   quisque suae tectique memor, nunc magna referto
>
>   facta, patrum laudes. ultro occurramus ad undam
>
>   dum trepidi egressisque labant vestigia prima.
>
>   **audentis Fortuna iuvat**.*

A very literal English translation:

> What you have all hoped for with your prayers is finally here: to break through with your right hands [i.e. with your weapons]. Mars himself gives strength to your hands. Now all of you, remember your wives and your roofs [i.e. homes], now think back to the great deeds [of the past], [and] the glories of our fathers [i.e. ancestors]. Now let's rush out into the waves to meet them, while the nervous [enemies] coming down [from their ships] take their first unsteady steps. **Fortune favors the daring!**

These lines are spoken by Turnus; the last is the one you want. Since *audentīs* is the participle of *audeō* "dare" I would translate this version as "Fortune favors the daring", but that's just a stylistic choice.

The choice between *audentīs* and *audentēs*, as Joonas mentions, is a stylistic one; they mean exactly the same thing in Classical times. I'd go with *-īs* just because it's what Vergil used.

Comment: I would add that the accusative ending *-es* instead of *-is* is a valid choice in classical Latin although not used by Virgil, so *audentes Fortuna iuvat* is a faithful rendering of the original.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Fair; added!

Comment: Re: the ending see https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/1618/39

Comment: cf. line 280, Gian Biago Conte, in the most recent, 2011 Teubner edition, "in manibus Mars ipse **, uiri!**"

Answer (score 0):

Fortuna (the goddess) favors the daring. The capitalization of the F is not a mere oversight. It is to distinguish between the goddess Fortuna, and the concept of fortune.

Comment: I guarantee Vergil did not distinguish case, and the goddess Fortuna is just the personification of the concept of fortune anyway.