# Latin Translation for "Death to the enemies of mankind"

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, motto

I'd like to translate "Death to the enemies of mankind" into Latin. How can I do that? If there are multiple ways of saying it, I would like it structured as close to a motto as possible, since that's what I intend to use it for.

Comment: “Latin” is a weird way to spell “High Gothic” :-P

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoriaReinstateCMs In Gothic, it's "Mortis xenos, adversa humanis". Just pick whatever Latin words that make the meaning clear to an English speaker. Ignore any grammar, that just makes stuff difficult.

Comment: As much as I like 40k, it's for my own fictional universe, so I'd prefer Latin xD

Comment: Out of interest: Who are the enemies of mankind?

Comment: It's a slogan for the Terran military forces, who fight within the larger Terran Union Army. All forces originating from Earth share this common motto, though they may be different otherwise, even to the extent of other mottos.

Answer (score 11):

I would go with

> Mors humanae gentis inimicis.

This is a literal translation that follows the original pretty closely: *mors* "death", *humanae gentis* "of the human race, of mankind", *inimicis* "to the enemies". Latin word order is flexible; this order sounds best to me, but others would be grammatically correct too.

(Note that if you ask Google Translate, it will tell you this means "Death is an enemy of mankind", which it does not. As has often been discussed on this site, Google Translate doesn't actually know Latin.)

Comment: Does classical Latin ever say "mors + dative" to mean "so-and-so must die"?

Comment: @fdb Good point -- come to think of it, maybe not (though possibly *mortem* acc. as object of some implied verb?). If it doesn't and if Classical idiom is important to the OP, maybe a looser paraphrase with e.g. *moriantur* is better.

Answer (score 3):

A quick translation of that phrase could be something like:

"Moriendum Hostibus Hominum"

This is a straightforward translation of what you're looking for. Many words could replace moriendum in this phrase, like fatum, letum, exitium, mors etc. I chose moriendum because it rounds out the phrase with a starting -um and an ending -um. That sentential symmetry was much liked by the Romans. Also, moriendum being a verb-turned-into-a-noun (gerund) feels much more active than a plain noun like those listed above.

I have fixed my mistake; hostis is now declined properly. In response to the comments on this post, I submit that Moriendum is acceptable with an implied to be verb (est). This would give a construction like "nunc est bibendum" in Ovid's Cleopatra ode. The intended translation of my submission is "(It is the time for) dying for the enemies of mankind."

Comment: Does that literally translate to what I asked for, or is it, like, similar in meaning? Google Translate seems to think it means "Taker of man's foes".

Comment: Shouldn't it be *hostibus*, dative of reference? (Though my sense is that *inimicus* would be a better choice -- *hostis* connotes armed conflict between nations, which doesn't to be quite what OP is looking for.)

Comment: @Nickimite: A gerund gives "dying is the enemy of men"; a gerundive: "it-ought-to-be-dying" rendered to "it must be death"; shouldn't it be dative hostibus/ inimicis--to the enemies of men?

Comment: The gerund in Latin doesn't have a nominative; the infinitive is used there.

Comment: @Budhaditya Ghosh One should never rely on Google Translate for Latin translations. Its translations are almost always wrong. Not that human students of Latin are always right (as you can tell from the comments on my post) but we're always more right than Google.

Comment: @Nickimite: Please see Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/10809/1982; "nunc est moriendum"--the best translation, using English impersonal pronoun, "one", is "now one must die";  presumably, the translation would be completed with (--the enemies of mankind).

Comment: In that example *'est'* is obligatory.

Answer (score 1):

How about "they shall die" - moriuntor hostis humanitatis

Comment: (or hostes - i think both is possible for nom.pl.)

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for the suggestion! Two remarks: (1) I think the one ending in *-is* is only possible in plural accusative, not nominative, so it'd have to be *hostes*. [See this for some details.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1615/79) (2) Your English translation suggests that you wanted to use future, which would be *morientur*. Or did you mean to use present tense? // You can always edit your questions and answers to add details or fix something.

Comment: I like *morientor*, but I don't think it means "they shall die". Rather it means, "let them die". Please come up with a better English phrase.