# Translation of lucis mortiat / reginae gloriae

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, song-lyrics

I am currently in the process of writing a review and I stumbled over these two Latin phrases in the lyrics that make scratch my head a bit.

> Lucis Mortiat (death to the light)
> Reginae Gloriae (glory to the queen)

My Latin is a bit rusty, because quite some time has passed since I had this in school, nevertheless the word **Mortiat** makes me scratch my head. The base of the word appears to be *mors*, but aside from this I am left a bit in the dark. I would expect something like *morte ad regem*, like in the case of a king; to name some example. Something that would have an imperative in it.

The second one is also slightly off. It is rather glory **of** the queen than glory **to** the queen.

Maybe someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not much to clarify in the first line, *mortiat* is not proper Latin. One might imagine a word like *mortire*, but the sentence would still not parse. Proper if perhaps not idiomatic Latin would be: *lux moriatur* (literally: “may the light die”). Other ways to say “death to X” were discussed in [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13694).

As for the second sentence, *reginae* does indeed mean “to the queen” – it is the dative. But it should be *gloria*, not *gloriae*. The plural is not forbidden, but it does not mean “glory,” but rather “glorious deeds.” Other than that, it is certainly idiomatic Latin; compare the famous *Gloria in excelsis Deo* (“Glory to God in the highest”), where *Deo* is also in the dative.

Comment: I was not entirely sure about the second phrase; as I says, it has been a while. There was something that bothered me about, but I could not pinpoint it. Well earned accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

To add on to Sebastian's answer, *ad* is primarily for motion, and should not be confused with an indirect object. It's the 'to' as in 'to/for' (I gave *him* the ball, I gave the ball *to him*), and not 'to/toward. You can't say "I gave the ball toward him," which is what you'd be saying with the *ad* + the accusative. The indirect object (*reginae*, *regi*) is what you want here.

Also, I noticed he was going for parallelism, so *mortiat* is probably just some jumbled transcription. The lyricist was probably going for something like:

> Luci mors
> Reginae gloria

This is a more literal translation of the English in parentheses. *Luci* is in the dative like *reginae*, and *mors* and *gloria* are both nominative singular.

Comment: I had Latin for a considerable amount of years and I know ad and its function. Stuff like that is obvious, while other ones are a bit blurred.

Comment: @ToReplyIsActuallyFree Ah, your "would expect ad +" was ambiguous then. I thought you meant that you thought it should have been ad + acc.